# Not able to make everything center aligned as per screen requirements

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-edittext, tablelayout

This is a  layout for my android  application.

I am not able to put everything centre aligned. Also When screen size changes, layout changes and looks messy. With the help of scroll view, am now able to look everything on screen but it don't looks good on screen size change.

Kindly help!

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >  



<TableLayout 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableRow>

    <TextView 
            android:text="@string/nameofitem"
            android:width="2dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
             />
    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/item_name_value"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
      <TextView 
            android:text="@string/category"
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" />


     </TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView 
            android:text="@string/item_description"
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" />


    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/item_description_value"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" 
            android:inputType="text"    />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/contact_info"
            android:width="2dp"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView 
            android:text="@string/Nameofperson"
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" />

    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/signup_item_person_name"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" 
            android:inputType="text"        />

</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <TextView 
            android:text="@string/emailid"
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" />

    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/emailid_seller_value"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" 
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"        />

 </TableRow>

 <TableRow>
    <TextView 
            android:text="@string/Phone_number"
            android:width="2dp" 
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginRight="-90dp" />

    <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/phone_number_seller_value"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"       
            android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" 
            android:width="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"  
            android:inputType="phone"       />

   </TableRow>

      <TableRow>
       <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/are_you_sure"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/are_you_sure"
            />
</TableRow>

<TableRow>
    <Button 
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:onClick="onClick13"/>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you tell how you want it to look in the end? _"everything center align"_ is confusing to understand! maybe draw it on a piece of paper or something.. take a photo and post it here..

Comment: Have you tried to make `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and `android:layout_gravity="center` on your `TableRow`?

Comment: Yes @Fllo I have tried that. But it was not working.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare Sure. Will upload a picture just a minute.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare Sorry! Not able to post image here.

Comment: center align means I want to put table on the centre of the page without taking screen size in account.

Comment: post a link to the image. Upload to http://imgur.com/!

Comment: lets say i put the table in the center.. what about the items in the table are they also center within the table? what about the left and right? Should they be empty or should the contents stretch to fit the screen? There are many possibilities and so I asked for a screenshot..

Comment: Thanks. @AmulyaKhare It worked now. I just changed TableRow properties.